# Why is CORSAIR opening and closing the same file thousands of times a minute?

Tags: windows, process-monitor

I've recently been playing around with Process Monitor, honestly being amazed at how many of my applications appear to be making useless calls to the disk.  One of the main culprits I saw were CORSAIR,  which appears to be making many, many calls to the same file.

[image]
<sub>(source: [femto.pw](https://i.femto.pw/rJtjcjsaM))</sub>

Is there a way to make it so that the CORSAIR utility does not request this file every few hundred milliseconds?

EDIT: A copy of the file it is trying to access, which does appear to exist can be found [here](https://i.femto.pw/SJ8dono6M.xml).  As far as I can tell, both my user and the SYSTEM user has read/write/modify/execute/full control access.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but it would probably be much easier on the community if you uploaded your picture utilizing the built-in Super User capabilities (stack.imgur.com) rather than another host.  By default, it is rather difficult to see.

Comment: Woops, sorry @Run5k, relatively new to this StackExchange community.  How do I do that?  Visiting http://stack.imgur.com/ doesn't seem to result in anything useful.

Comment: The problem is that it is unable to open the file, so it keeps trying.  (Not an answer because this does not say WHY it can't open the file)

Comment: Normally, you click on the [Image button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urr9z.jpg) in the toolbar to upload your picture.  However, @AFH is one of our community's very best contributors, and he already helped out regarding the hard-to-see aspect.

Comment: @davidgo Sorry, how can you tell that it's unable to open the file?  As far as I can see all the `RESULT`s are `SUCCESS`?  Also, added file, which doesn't seem to contain anything special (valid XML), it's permissions are normal as well.  Plus, thanks @Run5k for explaining how to embed images in the future ;)

Comment: Each set of lines starts Denied Access...

Comment: @davidgo I think it says "Desired Access", not "Denied Access".